# Delete favourites and history

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, bookmarks

I have an iPad using Safari as a browser.
[image]

As you can see I have a very long list of History and/Favorites in the left hand column. There are hundreds of duplicates. I can get rid of the 1 at a time but I've already deleted several hundred.

Is there any way to delete them all at once?

Or find a way to stop duplicating them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac, and you are using iCloud, I would recommend that you use the bookmark manager in macOS Safari to delete these. You should be able to select a vast amount of bookmarks using a <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd>.